# How to write templates with std::basic_string for C character types?

Tags: c++, templates, stdstring

The type for `std::basic_string` (`char`, `wchar_t`, ...) can't be deduced from `const char*` or `const wchar_t*`:

```
#include <string>

template <class chTy>
void f(std::basic_string<chTy> s, chTy c) {}

int main()
{
    const char* narrowCS = "";
    char narrowC = {};
    const wchar_t* wideCS = L"";
    wchar_t wideC = {};
    std::string narrowS;
    std::wstring wideS;

    // The calls with C string arguments will throw in VS2017:
    //  - C2672: no matching overloaded function found
    //  - C2784: could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_string<_Elem,std::char_traits<_Elem>,std::allocator<_Ty>>' from 'const char *'
    //f(narrowCS, narrowC);
    //f(wideCS, wideC);
    f(narrowS, narrowC);
    f(wideS, wideC);
}
```

Two variants could solve this: Either

```
template <class chTy>
void f(std::basic_string<chTy> s, chTy c) {}
template <class chTy>
void f(const chTy* s, chTy c) { f(std::basic_string<chTy>(s), c); }
```

or as overloads using implicit construction of s

```
void f(std::string s, char c) {}
void f(std::wstring s, wchar_t c) {}
```

Are there more elegant solutions using `std::basic_string`?

Comment: Do you like `f<char>(narrowCS, narrowC)` :P

Comment: @Rakete1111, is adding deduction guides in std namespace legal in C++17?

Comment: @Incomputable No, you get UB. See http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.std#4.4

Comment: try adding all template arguments to `basic_string` (it has 3 of them, not only one)

Comment: @Rakete1111, may be putting the character first will make it work?

Comment: @Incomputable Nope, you don't get implicit conversions if you use deduction.

Comment: @Hcorg `std::char_traits` and `std::allocator` can't be deduced from char/wchar_t.